# Real and generated Enter key press behave different on the editable div

Tags: javascript, html, newline, contenteditable, keydown

I need to change the editable div behavior with the replacement of the key for adding new line with Enter to Ctrl+Enter. I tried to do this with simulating Enter Keyboard event when the user pressed Ctrl+Enter. It did not work, and I do not understand why, and this 'why' is my main question.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ParadoxMaster/nxjcr7gL/

```js
let editDiv = document.getElementById("edit_div");
let ctrlEnter = false;
editDiv.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey) {

    console.log("Ctrl + Enter");
    ctrlEnter = true;
    let simulatedEnterDown = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      "charCode": e.charCode,
      "bubbles": e.bubbles,
      "cancelable": e.cancelable,
      "composed": e.composed,
      "code": e.code,
      "key": e.key,
      "keyCode": e.keyCode,
      "location": e.location,
      "which": e.which,
      "sourceCapabilities": e.sourceCapabilities,
      "view": e.view
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(simulatedEnterDown);

  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    if (!ctrlEnter) {

      console.log("Just enter down");
      e.preventDefault();

    } else {

      console.log("Fake enter down");
      ctrlEnter = false;

    }

  }
});
```

```css
div#edit_div {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="edit_div" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

If remove the line with the PreventDefault call, the real and generated events will be the same, but they behave differently. Why this happenning, and what needs to do, to make the approach work?

P.S. I saw the answer in which it was proposed to manually add wrappers for the new line, but I’m interested in this option with events.

Comment: The console in the fiddle says when the user presses enter or ctrl+enter, what's the problem? What's "not working"?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy his question is that why isnt a newline being added when `ctrl + enter` is pressed?

Comment: @AdityaShankar, right